# Can you lose the legend rank in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Can you lose the legend rank in Hearthstone? I have seen pro players lose a lot in videos but they never seem to lose legend (except at the end of the season). Is it possible to be demoted from legend or are they still winning some games that are not part of the videos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, once you reach legend you cannot lose legend until the season ends.